# Linux Mint Changing current version of Python

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

I have installed python 3.7 but still using and showing version of python 2.7 . I want to change it to 3.. I searched it but ı can't did it.

Comment: Just type python3 in your terminal and see if you get the python3 version

Comment: I want to use pip last version and python2.7 supporting version 9 it is insufficient.EDİT: my pip version is lastest version but ı want to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should not change your syslink `python` to use python 3** because it is most likely that your system is using that syslink to python 2 for its own tasks and processes, if you change that, you may broke your system.

As Sammy said in a comment, you should use `python3` to use that version.

On the pip side, it is probably that your python 3 does not have pip include (it should have it, but I have seen a lot of Python 3 without it). You can check if you have pip doing: `python3 -m pip`. The `-m` param is used to execute modules of python installed.

**If you do not have pip installed**, you can install it following this (which I recommend because always work): https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

That is:

- Download a script to install pip: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
- Execute the script in order to install pip (with sudo because you're going to modify your system): `sudo python3 get-pip.py`

Now you should have pip installed and doing `python3 -m pip` again should show you the help of pip.

**If you have pip already installed** and no pip3 command in your system, you can always create an alias to `python3 -m pip` with the name `pip3` and problem solved. Also if you don't know or do not want to create alias or executables in the /usr/bin folder, you can always keep using `python3 -m pip`.

PS: It is highly recommended to use virtualenvs when developing with python. If you do not know what it is, here it is a link to the docs: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: actually ı removed python with purdge and redirected path . Thanks guys fist bump.

Comment: somebody vote -1, but without any explanation of why this answer could be bad. Ok.